# VMWare ESXi 4.1 - Shrink Thin disk (without Storage vMotion or "sdelete"/filling disk with 0's)

Tags: storage, vmware, shrink

I have a 100GB Thin disk which is about 80GB vmdk file on the storage device. The disk really only has 10GB of files stored on it (ie ~70GB free). How can I shrink the ~80GB vmdk back down to ~10GB noting that the VMWare tools show the "shrink" option isn't available and I can't use any of the other techniques I've seen (such as sdelete/zero-fill and "vStorage motion" it) because either a) I don't have another temporary storage location and b) the current storage location doesn't have enough raw space left to allow for the expanded zero fill.

Are there any other methods to shrink a vmdk on ESXi 4.1?

Answer (score 0):

First , defragment the disk inside guest. Then detach (remove only from VM) the vmdk, edit the vmdk descriptor file diskname.vmdk, with new size, follow the below link

http://www.vmwarearena.com/2013/03/shrink-virtual-machine-vmdk.html